# how can i start a java application (jar) with another look & feel?

Tags: java, user-interface, jar

I am using a java application ([weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)) , and i wonder if i could change the look and feel of its graphical user interface, because it really looks very ugly with this blue steel theme.

When i proramm a gui in java i remember i can change the look&feel with the UIManager.setLookAndFeel() method.

Can i do something similar when i run the jar file e.g. passing in any parameters ?!?!

I am using linux (crunchbang).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should intercept the command line parameter by your own, or with this jvm parameter :

```
-Dswing.metalTheme=steel
```

Take a look at the reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more information .

Answer (score 0):

Use this

> UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

The best I feel. Similar to Netbeans or eclipse look.

For windows:
`-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`

For linux not sure though about the feel
`java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`

Comment: Hello and thank you. I think i will have no luck with this. I wrote a simple java programm which executes the getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()) and it only returns 'javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel'. however if i start the application with your -Dswing param for the gtkLookAndFeel, the application successfully starts with a the different theme, but crashes when i click on a button with a Nullpointer exception: in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException weka.gui.explorer.PreprocessPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(Unknown Source)